# SQL Join empty dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table that has missing dates. The way this database is formed is that on the day it has an entry, it displays the cumulative metric.

```
    Project      Date       Cumulative

    Project A    10/1       5
    Project A    10/2       6
    Project A    10/4       7
    Project A    10/7       8
    Project A    10/8       9
```

I can merge this onto a date table to get the full range of dates, but I don't know how to keep the previous dates' value. This can skip 1 or more days.

Ideal table

```
    Project      Date       Cumulative

    Project A    10/1       5
    Project A    10/2       6
    Project A    10/3       6
    Project A    10/4       7
    Project A    10/5       7
    Project A    10/6       7
    Project A    10/7       8
    Project A    10/8       9
```

Comment: mysql and sql-server is two different rdbms. Please tag only one

Comment: `I can merge this onto a date table to get the full range of dates` Please show this query

Comment: if you want the ability to look back/ahead, you should check **window functions** which most rdbms have nowadays. we can't quite write the right query if you don't settle on the rdbms, please tag properly.

Comment: modified the tags

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, if we assume you have a table like this (with pre-aggregated cumulatives for a given date):

```
create table projects (project varchar(50), day date, cumulative int);
```

And it has the following data in it:

```
insert projects (project, day, cumulative)
select 'project a', '2022-10-01', 5
union all
select 'project a', '2022-10-02', 6
union all
select 'project a', '2022-10-04', 7
union all
select 'project a', '2022-10-07', 8
union all
select 'project a', '2022-10-08', 9
union all
select 'project b', '2022-10-01', 5
union all
select 'project b', '2022-10-02', 6
union all
select 'project b', '2022-10-04', 7
union all
select 'project b', '2022-10-07', 8
union all
select 'project b', '2022-10-08', 9
union all
select 'project c', '2022-10-01', 1
union all
select 'project c', '2022-10-02', 2
union all
select 'project c', '2022-10-07', 12
union all
select 'project c', '2022-10-08', 15;
```

And you have a dates table similar to the following (as you mention in your question):

```
create table dates (day date);
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-01';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-02';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-03';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-04';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-05';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-06';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-07';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-08';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-09';
insert dates (day) select '2022-10-10';
```

Multiple ways you could go about it - here are 2 possibilities. Both of them first create a set of data that contains all date and project combinations between a set of dates.

The first leverages an APPLY operation to get the row from the projects table that matches or is closest to the date in the out set. The second uses an aggregate function (max) to get the largest value from the resolved set. The second method assumes that the cumulative number for a given project/date combination cannot decrease over time - if that is not ok from a requirements perspective, you'd have to look at other options that leverage either the APPLY or similar, or perhaps an inner [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operation.

```
-- APPLY
SELECT  pd.day, pd.project, c.cumulative
FROM    (
        SELECT  d.day, pn.project
        FROM    dbo.dates d
        CROSS APPLY
                (SELECT DISTINCT pn.project FROM dbo.projects pn) pn
        WHERE   d.day BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-15'
        ) pd
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 p.cumulative
        FROM    dbo.projects p
        WHERE   p.project = pd.project
                AND p.day <= pd.day
        ORDER BY
                p.day DESC
        ) c
ORDER BY
        pd.day, pd.project;

-- MAX over partition
SELECT  pd.day, pd.project,
        COALESCE(p.cumulative, MAX(p.cumulative) OVER (PARTITION BY pd.project ORDER BY pd.day, pd.project)) AS cumulative
FROM    (
        SELECT  d.day, pn.project
        FROM    dbo.dates d
        CROSS APPLY
                (SELECT DISTINCT pn.project FROM dbo.projects pn) pn
        WHERE   d.day BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-15'
        ) pd
LEFT JOIN
        dbo.projects p
ON      p.project = pd.project
        AND p.day = pd.day
ORDER BY
        pd.day, pd.project;
```